If the file is modified during debugging in Vscode, the execution line points to a strange place, is there a way to fix this?
As in the title, I am using debug mode in vscode.
I'm running the code line by line and tracking the steps (pressing F11), as shown in the picture below, the highlights indicating the next run point to the strange code.
enter image description here
(Please understand that the image is not immediately visible due to the lack of reputation.)
My expectation is that the file will be modified in the middle of the run, and the debugger can't seem to reflect it.
(To match the version, run 'pip uninstall ultralytics' before running debugger, which will be installed again in later code runs.)
My project is 'Multi Object Tracking, MOT' (reference below)
https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/yolo_tracking
All you want is for the debugger to point to a proper line of execution.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do this.
(If there is any information that needs to be resolved, I will add it quickly.)
Save the file (ctrl + s), turn the file off and on.
(I didn't turn vscode off and on. I simply shut down the file at the top, turned it on again. (It doesn't affect execution))

I would be surprised if that was possible. The reason I feel like it is unlikely to be supported is that the python you are running and debugging is in memory, not what is on the disk. Maybe, if you are debugging and want to inject a command or reset a variable you could use the "DEBUG CONSOLE" tab.

Thank you for the comments. I' ll check it.  :)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The debugger works by associating breakpoints and execution points with specific lines in the source code. If you change the source code, these associations will become incorrect.
